# Flash + How to enable click through movie frame

Tags: html, flash

Is it possible to configure a flash SWF so that it not only is transparent, but also let's users click through to the HTML below?

*The scenario:* Imagine a horizontal drop down menu. That menu is a transparent SWF. For it to have a drop down I need to set the movie dimensions for something like width: 1000px; height: 250px;
Those 250px will overlap an html slider. Users won't be able to click the slider because the flash movie has a higher z-index.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps trying to change z-index with java script dynamically and using AS3's ExternalInterface.

http://www.hardcode.nl/archives_155/article_334-call-javascript-function-from-as3-and-viceversa

For transparency there should be an option in your publish settings.